# Can´t load image in background-image:url from my files

Tags: css

Im just trying to make a simple web page for practice but i cant load any image in my .css file.

This is the part where it gives me errors.

```
 headerBarImage{
   height: 54px;
   background-image: 
   url("C:\Users\crvrb\Desktop\AtomProyects\webPage1\images\blueSky.jpg");
 }
```

I tried taking out the semicolons or adding ' ' but it doesnt work

It works fine if i upload it from the html file

```
 <img 
 src="C:\Users\crvrb\Desktop\AtomProyects\webPage1\images\blueSky.jpg" 
 alt="Blue Sky">
```

Also im using google Chrome Web Server to open the files.

Comment: It's usually a best practice to use a local server when developing for the web. You can install XAMPP or MAMP and go from there.

Comment: I guess in CSS context, it probably interprets this as a relative URL. You can try explicitly specifying the file protocol (`file:///C:/Users/…`, note that all the slashes should be forward ones), but as already said, you should really rather install a local web server. The closer you keep things during development, to what the “real” conditions will be, when that website gets uploaded to a live server at some point, the less trouble you’ll usually have.

Comment: Can you modify the file path to be relative? Eg: url("../images/blueSky.jpg")

Comment: Thought i´ve tried that but its working now thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

In a [CSS string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/string) a `\` character is an escape character (in HTML it is not) so needs to be expressed as `\\`.

Windows file paths provide all sorts of trouble though. Use relative URLs instead (the `/` character isn't special in either HTML nor CSS).

Comment: I wondered why it showed it as an error but after using relative URLs its working fine thank you!